# ListView Control Can't Drag and Drop in Virtual Mode

Tags: .net, listview, virtualmode

I have searched and I cannot find an answer to my question.  I have a ListView that is moving to VirtualMode, but when I attempt a drag over operation, it fails.  It can't find the correct insertion index because the items are virtual.  How do you do a proper drag over of a ListView Item when in virtual mode?

Basically the problem is that NearestIndex is returning -1 no matter where the mouse is.  This code worked prior to moving to virual mode.

```
int theTargetIdx = InsertionMark->NearestIndex( thePoint );

if ( theTargetIdx > -1 )
{
    System::Drawing::Rectangle theItemBounds = GetItemRect( theTargetIdx );
    if ( thePoint.Y > theItemBounds.Top + (theItemBounds.Height / 2) )
    {
        InsertionMark->AppearsAfterItem = true;
    }
    else
    {
        InsertionMark->AppearsAfterItem = false;
    }
}
else
{
    aArgs->Effect = System::Windows::Forms::DragDropEffects::None;  
}

InsertionMark->Index = theTargetIdx;
```

Comment: You need to supply some source code for what you have tried

Comment: The point is returned from PointToClient of the x and y positions of the mouse.

Comment: Oh, and this is in OnDragDrop of the ListView control in question.